# polyphase filter for decimation/interpolation how to split and pick up the phase?

Tags: signal-processing, interpolation

I am trying to figure out how a polyphase filter used for decimation and interpolation works. After  reviewing the theory, looks like the number of phases or branches in the circuit is related to the scale of the filter, like if you decimating by 4, M=4 , you have 4 branches of circuit. But my question is related to the phases , for M=4 (for example), I will have 4 sets of coefficients filters: h0 , h1, h2, h3; then the signal separation will be:

```
    x0*h0 
    x1*h1 
    x2*h2 
    x3*h3 
    x4*h0
    x5*h1
    x6*h2
```

...
and so on .. right ? But then when you have a fixed set of phases ? or anybody knows a different topology to implement this filter with a single architecture that can encompass decimation and interpolation ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a "fixed set of phases"?

Comment: for the case when you have a pre determined number of phases and the scale factor (either for interpolation or decimation)  says which phase to pick. the set of phases is the same sync function shifted in time. I do not know if there is any literature explaining it. But the developer implemented a polyphase algorithm with a fixed number of phase, let 's say 32, and the scale factor says which phase to pick from the set of 32.

Comment: It really boils down to the architecture of the filter. Here is a good example that, I believe addresses your question about which phase to choose and how: http://www.zipcores.com/datasheets/app_note_zc003.pdf